# iteratively find value in dictionary by using key from list using map lambda or list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, series

i have a dictionary

```
d={1: [3, 6, 9], 3: [1, 6, 9], 6: [1, 3, 9], 9: [1, 3, 6], 2: [4, 7], 4: [10, 7], 7: [2, 4], 5: [8, 10], 8: [5, 10], 10: [5, 8, 11], 11: [10, 8, 3]}
```

and a series

```
x=pd.Series([3,8,9])
```

for each value of list, i want to find the corresponding values in dictionary.

i am using for loop

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    n=d[x.iloc[i]]
```

the expected output is

```
[1, 3, 6]
```

but as data has 1.6 M rows, for loop is slowing down the process. I think map lamda method, or list comprehension can increase the speed. But i am having trouble in both, i tried some thing like this

```
n=[d[x] for i in range(len(x))]
```

, but its not working. any way to achieve the goal

Comment: All of this is completely irrelevant because you're using pandas, haven't shown the dataframe, why you've decided to iterate a dict or what the expected output is. Pandas is a completely different beast to python and has all sorts of ways of tapping into vectorized calculations.

Comment: i have two files, one of them is in the form of dictionary, because i need key value pair. The other file is in the form of data frame. Using one column of data frame that is ID, using it as key in dictionary i have to find corresponding values. Then i have to use those values to find their related data in complete data frame.

Answer (score 1):

This should be faster than using all ilocs:

```
for i in x:
    n=d[i]
```

For a list of 1000 numbers this timeits: 147 µs ± 7.51 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

while OPs loop with ilocs :
33.8 ms ± 1.35 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Comment: This loop does nothing at all. The OP should not be iterating the df and this loop does not change any values. It's also not going to to do the same as what code they start with.

Comment: neither does OPs loop, so i assume he does some logic inside it.

Comment: @Christian Sloper i tried your way you told, and the  execution time is reduced a lot.. thanks Man

Comment: If speed is very important it is actually a bit faster to convert it to a list when iterating: `for i in x.tolist():`

Comment: using `for i in x.tolist()` is taking 170 ms and the approach by @ChristianSloper is taking around 130 ms, its a big size series, i am still thinking for a better solution

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
pd.Series(d).loc[x]
Out[47]: 
3    [1, 6, 9]
8      [5, 10]
9    [1, 3, 6]
dtype: object
```

If need list

```
pd.Series(d).loc[x].tolist()
Out[68]: [[1, 6, 9], [5, 10], [1, 3, 6]]
```